# Many to many eloquent query Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a students table, a courses table and a student_courses pivot table.

My models are as following:

```
{
    public $timestamps= false;
    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class);

    }
}
```

```
class Course extends Model
{

    public $timestamps= false;
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
    }
}
```

My tables look like this:

```
        Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->String('code');
            $table->String('name');
```

```
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first');
            $table->string('last');
```

```
Schema::create('course_student', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses');
            $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students');
```

I've successfully added students and courses, and attached students to courses, so I know my models are working.

I am wanting to create a query function in my controller that I can access in a view. I'm wanting a query that gives me a list of each student and what course they're in.

For example

> Student1 Course1
>
> Student1 Course2
>
> Student2 Course 1

How can i make a query to use in my view, using a foreach to enter the data into a table? I've successfully outputted all students names and course names, but I don't understand how to query the pivot table

Comment: Can you show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on you controller:

```
$students = Student::with('courses')->get();
```

and inside the view:

```
@foreach($students as $student)
    @foreach($student->courses as $course )
       {{ $student->first . $student->last }} {{ $course->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you
Had been missing the ::with and nested foreach

Answer (score 1):

As you defined the relationship you don't have to manually query the pivot table.

I would do something like that in the controller:

```
$students = Student::with('courses')->get();
```

As I understand you want to put the data in a table, here is a two columns example:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Courses</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach($students as $student)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $student->first}} {{ $student->last}}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach($student->courses as $course)
                {{ $course->name }},
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
<tbody>
</table>
```

You will get this this of table:

```
| Student Name | Courses    |
|:-------------|-----------:|
| John         | C1, C2, C3 |
| Marc         | CA, CB, CC |
```

Comment: have a look at my answer... it's  a many to many, so a student has many courses

Answer (score 1):

Get data of students with courses

```
$students = Student::with('courses')->get();
```

in view

```
@foreach($students as $student)
    {{ $student->first }} {{ $student->last }} // to display student name

    @foreach($student->courses as $course) // loop of courses of student
      {{ $course->name }} // to display student name
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```